# NSMutableArray items are all exactly the same

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray

I have a set of map annotations that I am iterating over to store into my own data model. I have checked with log statements to ensure that the coordinates are in fact different, which they are. However, when I attempt to iterate over that same array of pins and add the coordinate to my model all of the coordinates are exactly the same.

I know that my loop is the culprit, but can't quite figure out why that's happening:

```
NSMutableArray *modelArray = [NSMutableArray new];
    for (PinObject *currentPin in self.mapPins) {
        CLLocation *pinCoordinate = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:currentPin.coordinate.latitude   longitude:currentPin.coordinate.longitude];

        AnnotationCameraModel *cameraModel = [self.cameraModel initWithData:pinCoordinate];
        coordinates[i] = currentPin.coordinate;
        [modelArray addObject:cameraModel];
    }

 for (AnnotationCameraModel *model in modelArray) {
        NSLog(@"Coordinate: %@", model.coordinate);
    }
```

When I log my points I end up with:

```
Coordinate: <+14.56841634,+121.03354250> +/- 0.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 11/17/16, 9:00:14 PM Philippine Standard Time
Coordinate: <+14.56841634,+121.03354250> +/- 0.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 11/17/16, 9:00:14 PM Philippine Standard Time
Coordinate: <+14.56841634,+121.03354250> +/- 0.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 11/17/16, 9:00:14 PM Philippine Standard Time
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I'd wager those logged coordinates are the *last* coordinates in your mapPins array, right? The @RokJarc and [ampersand]riyaz answers both look right to me.  In short, you're adding the same object (cameraModel) to the array over and over, mutating that object each time by improperly calling it's init method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless `self.cameraModel` (property of the object holding this code) is some kind of factory object that produces `AnnotationCameraModel` objects with a method `initWithData:` your problem lies in line:

```
AnnotationCameraModel *cameraModel = [self.cameraModel initWithData:pinCoordinate];
```

I suspect this property is just a simple `AnnotationCameraModel` object and it's initializer (depends on how it's written) returns itself.

Change that line to:

```
AnnotationCameraModel *cameraModel = [[AnnotationCameraModel alloc] initWithData:pinCoordinate];
```

Line `coordinates[i] = currentPin.coordinate;` also doesn't make much sense. You *probably* want something in the lines of `coordinates[i++] = currentPin.coordinate;`

Comment: This was exactly it. I was improperly overriding the init method in my class. Worked out just fine. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

There should be a two part creation

```
1 -  alloc 
2 -  init
```

You are basically initialising an already initialised object.

In every init method there would be a check

```
if (self == nil)
{
self = [super init];
}
return self;
```

so basically

```
[self.cameraModel initWithData:pinCoordinate]
```

does nothing but returning `self` because it is not `nil`.

Do this

```
 AnnotationCameraModel *cameraModel = [[AnnotationCameraModel alloc]initWithData:pinCoordinate];
```